Pandoc Converter: Implement Grid Tables for new format
I have implemented a reader for a custom XML format, in Haskell. Currently, I'm using the normal 'Table' and when I convert to Latex/HTML/Docx, table cells have no borders, and no cell merging is possible.
What is the simplest way to implement grid tables in my new reader?

Have a look at the grid_tables extension.

@HeikoTheißen I was referring to that extension. It is implemented for Markdown, but I don't know how to do the same for my custom format

You don't say what your custom input format is, nor how you implemented that reader.
But if you're wondering what Haskell ADT you're supposed to generate that corresponds exactly to what the markdown reader does for a specific grid table, then feed that markdown to pandoc -t native.

Thank you, that command is very helpful. The format I wrote a reader for is an internal one we wrote for our reports. It's XML with custom tags and attributes.

Great, I hope it answered your question then?

I am honestly not sure. I am still getting tables without any vertical cell borders, and the merged cells don't have seperate horizontal borders. I made sure to reproduce the same AST that grid tables produce. I will probably mark your answer as the solution if I don't get any other replies.

if the other commandline arguments (like --template) are the same, and you supply the same AST, then you should get the exact same output. Borders seem like something that are set in HTML/LaTeX template though.

I assumed they have the borders accounted for in the default Latex template that Pandoc impilicitly uses for PDF conversions. It looks like it's not the case. I'm puzzled as to why such a common use case is not even considered.

I suppose it's a question of style...

@Seifounage That's because unnecessary lines are considered bad style that can make  reading a table harder. Typographic wisdom has it that ink on a page should transport information. Table lines don't do that, the information is already in the alignment. LaTeX isn't built to support bad typography. However, if this is a hard requirement for your use-case, then consider to generate PDFs by going through HTML (--pdf-engine=weasyprint). Adding cell borders via CSS is very easy.

@tarleb I have finished styling it via CSS and weasyprint yielded great results. However, it took 4 minutes for a document that took wkhtmltopdf 15 seconds to compile. The only downside to wkhtmltopdf is that I'm having some formatting issues with it right now.
